# Silverstripe - Retrieving POST array within an array

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post, silverstripe

I have a form which I am using POST to post to the HTTP headers. I am trying to print_r the variables but I am not sure how to as the variables are in arrays within an array.

print_r($_POST); gives me

```
Array ( [y] => Array ( [0] => 124 ) [x] => Array ( [0] => 02:23PM ) )
```

My code:

```
public function index(SS_HTTPRequest $request) {

    if($request->postVars(y)) {
        print_r ($request);         
    }
}
```

I know I am missing something but not sure what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `postVars`, which gives you *all* the post variables. What you want, to get a single postVar, is something like this:

        `$request = $this->getRequest();
        Debug::dump($request->postVar('x'));`

Comment: Thank you very much